# JustGage - change gauge's background color

Tags: html, colors, background, gauge

I'm using justgage.1.0.1.js on my ASP page. I have configured colors for the progress line into 4 sectors like this:

```
var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge1",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Some Title",
    showMinMax: 0,
    label: '0 of 2',
    levelColorsGradient: false,
    countComplete: 0,
    countTotal: 2,
    levelColors: [ "#ff0000", "#ff9900",  "#ffcc00", "#cccc00" ]
});
```

And in case countComplete = 0 it chows me an empty pipe with a grey background color:

[image]

What I need is to change this empty pipe's background to red, but only if countComplete equals 0 and countTotal is greater than 0. In all other cases the background should stay gray:

``[image]
[image]
[image]

If this is possible to do, can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured this out. To change the background of the gauge line, you just have to add a parameter to the gauge's body:

```
gaugeColor: "#ff0000"
```